# How to Set up IP Specific Virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

The following is my current sites-available.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin heuyie@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ServerName heuyie.com
    ServerAlias www.heuyie.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to host another domain on this server, so I want to specify IP for this virtual host. So, I rewrote the first line like:

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
```

Then, things stopped working. Why?
Currently, this is the only domain on this server, by the way. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use name based virtual hosts ?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add

> Listen 172.20.30.40:80